# Laravel Socialite Providers Reddit 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I am using Socialite Providers for Reddit with Laravel 5.2.  In an attempt to address a Reddit error ('too many requests') during authentication I am having difficulty overriding the Socialite Provider method to add a custom header ('User-Agent') to the authentication request.

Here are the details.

The original problem is that I am getting an error during authentication with Reddit:

```
ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
Client error: `POST https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token` 
resulted in a `429 Too Many Requests` response:
{"error": 429}
```

I can fix the error by modifying the **vendor/socialiteproviders\reddit\src\Provider.php** method called **getAccessToken** to include a header called 'User-Agent'.

```
$response = $this->getHttpClient()->post($this->getTokenUrl(), [
        'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json',
            'User-Agent' => 'mydomain.com: v1.0 (by /u/reddituser)'],
        'auth' => [$this->clientId, $this->clientSecret],
        'form_params' => $this->getTokenFields($code),
    ]);
```

The problem with this solution is that my modifications can easily be lost with an update to the vendor files. Instead I would like to extend the Providers class and override the getAccessToken method.

I am able to get the ServiceProvider to register my custom method but I can't seem to get the custom method to actually run in place of the original.

Here is my code

app\Library\CustomRedditProvider.php (notice the dd which is never executed)

```
namespace app\Library\redditOverride;

use SocialiteProviders\Reddit\Provider;

class CustomRedditProvider extends Provider {

    // public function getAccessToken($code)
    public function getAccessToken($code)
    {

       dd('RedditCustomProvider getAccessToken');
       $response = $this->getHttpClient()->post($this->getTokenUrl(), [
        'headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json',
            'User-Agent' => 'mydomain.com: v1.0 (by /u/reddituser)'],
        'auth' => [$this->clientId, $this->clientSecret],
        'form_params' => $this->getTokenFields($code),
       ]);

       $this->credentialsResponseBody = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

       return $this->parseAccessToken($response->getBody());
    }
}
```

app/Providers/RedditOverrrideServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class RedditOverrideServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['customredditprovider'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new CustomRedditProvider();
        });
    }
}
```

config/app.php

```
\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RedditOverrideServiceProvider::class,
```

composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/library"
    ],
```